# having (Conversion failed ) error in SQL Server

Tags: sql

When I create a table using bellow SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE student(studentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,studnetName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,birthday Date)
```

Bellow operations(SQL commands) show me an error:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745','Ahmed','24-06-1997')
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745','sara','28-03-2000')
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745','Ali','12-02-2007')
```

the exact error is:

> ( Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string).

Can anybody help to explain why it happens?

Comment: `'24-06-1997'` is not a `date`, its a string representing a date. So it needs to be converted to a `date`. There are many, many formats in which dates can be represented, and your database cannot guess. Best to use ISO format: `'19970624'`

Comment: Try to add date in MM-dd-yyyy format in your insert query

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a typo in "studnetName"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify your database.  Most databases support strings in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` (an ISO 8601-compatible format) for date constants:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'Ahmed', '1997-06-24');
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'sara', '2000-03-28');
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'Ali', '2007-02-12');
```

In Standard SQL, date constants are supported by using the `date` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'Ahmed', DATE '1997-06-24');
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'sara', DATE '2000-03-28');
INSERT INTO student VALUES('226745', 'Ali', DATE '2007-02-12');
```

I would also advise you to list the columns explicitly when using `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because sql engine can't figure out the date format automatically (probably confused between m-d-y and d-m-y)

so you can specify the dateformat before you insert, ex in sql server:

```
set dateformat dmy;
```

and the same situation in other dbms